# Mysql- One table Two query in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table to store customer expenses like

```
Card_id   |   days          | ytl(expense-$)  
1           2014-05-21         50
2           2014-06-12         30
2           2014-06-13         20
3           2014-05-13         20
3           2014-06-20         20
3           2014-05-13         35
3           2014-06-20         26
```

I need people whose expenses exceed $40 in each of May and June months.

```
SELECT DISTINCT card_id
FROM expenses
WHERE date(days) > DATE("2014-05-01")
  AND date(days) < DATE("2015-06-30")
GROUP BY card_id HAVING SUM(YTL) >= 40
```

This query gives me total of two months.
So it returns card_id: 1-2-3. I need just 3

I cannot use **intersect**, because I'm using MySql.
I tried **inner join** but I  cannot solve it.

How can i do this?

Best Regards

Comment: save some of us the trouble and start a http://sqlfiddle.com/ showing how close you've gotten to your solution

Comment: i just want to clarify, you want to display the Card_id with expense in May+June is over 40? right?

Comment: No, I want to display card_id with expense over 40 in May and over 40 in June. I mean, he must expense each month over $40

Comment: I wonder if this data set is adequately representative for the purposes of providing a definitive answer. And note that your dataset lacks a PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:-

```
SELECT card_id
FROM
(
    SELECT card_id, MONTH(days) AS card_month, SUM(YTL) as card_sum
    FROM expenses
    WHERE days BETWEEN "2014-05-01" AND "2015-06-30"
    GROUP BY card_id, card_month
    HAVING card_sum >= 40
) sub0
GROUP BY card_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

This has a sub query that gets the sum for each card for each month, using HAVIING to check that the sum for each month is more than 40.

This sub query is then checked to find cards where the count is 2 (ie, 2 rows for that car from the sub query, one for each month).

If you need a bigger date range you might need to tweak this to take account of having the same month number in 2 years in the results from the sub query.

Comment: It returns error like; **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE date(days) BETWEEN DATE("2014-05-01") AND DATE("2014-06-30")
    GROUP BY ' at line 5**